# Packaging class files from multiple projects

Tags: sbt

I'm using SBT 0.13.0 and have the following configuration:

```
lazy val remington = project.in(file("remington"))
lazy val mossberg = project.in(file("mossberg")).dependsOn(remington)
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(mossberg)
```

When I run the package task in the "mossberg" project, the class files from the "remington" project are not included in the generated jar.  How do I include the class files from the "remington" project in the generated jar when I package the "mossberg" project?

Comment: Not absolutely sure, but I think you might need sbt-assembly for this.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `package` task create a modular JAR, a JAR file with only the class files from the current project. Modular JARs give you the most flexibility so it's preferable to publish them. But for deployment etc, if you want to aggregate the class files there are a few ways I can think of.

### sbt-assembly

[sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) creates a fat JAR, a JAR that includes all of its dependencies including library dependencies and Scala libraries.

### Getting values from multiple scopes

sbt 0.13 also lets you aggregate the task results across multiple scopes (including subprojects), so you could use that to make an artificial project that includes `sources` from both projects. See the `sources` example from [Getting values from multiple scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#getting-values-from-multiple-scopes).